# Pymongo collection.find_and_modify, specifying index to use? $hint?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-indexes

My find_and_modify query is using the wrong index.

Is there a way, using PyMongo, to hint the correct index (by name or otherwise)?

Nothing seems to mention this at all in any docs...

Comment: Could you please provide the exact example of the query, and what index is being hit ?

Comment: According to [SERVER-7105](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7105), using `$hint` with `FindAnyModify` isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to SERVER-7105, using $hint with FindAnyModify isn't supported.

*Posted originally by [JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk)*